# Streaming audio/video from browser to Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, streaming, video-capture, audio-capture

I have to make some kind of service, where people can record a video/an audio from the browser and watch/listen it later.

Is there any way to capture audio/video from the browser and instantly upload it to Microsoft Azure cloud service, that would be work on mobile devices too?

I've found how to upload existing video with C# or Java, but I need to stream it to Azure or in an extreme case somehow save it to the my server and upload it with C#/Java to Azure.

I would be grateful for any idea!